Indirect control, camera fixation at level
I’m creating my own puzzle game using indirect control. That is, the level has a fixed camera, and you can click on objects with the mouse to move them. I’ve encountered the following issue: I need to make sure that when switching between multiple characters (when they enter the active phase and can be controlled), the view does not switch to their own camera but remains on the main level camera that I have set up.
Here’s the desired outcome: I start the game, and the camera is fixed above the game level. The first character moves. I press E to switch to another active character; the second character starts moving, but the camera view doesn’t change. And this should continue infinitely. Currently, after the first switch between characters, the camera position gets messed up.
Здравствуйте! Создаю свою игру в жанре головоломки, использую непрямое управление. То есть на уровне фиксированная камера, и с помощью мышки можно нажимать на объекты, чтобы их перемещать. Возникла такая проблема: мне нужно сделать так, чтобы несколько персонажей при переключении на них (когда они входят в активную фазу и ими можно управлять) не переключали мой вид на свою собственную камеру, а оставались на основной камере уровня, которую я настроил. Какой итог: нажимаю запустить игру, камера фиксированная над игровым уровнем, двигается первый персонаж. Нажимаю E, переключаю активного персонажа, он начинает двигаться, а вид камеры не меняется. И так до бесконечности. Поскольку сейчас после первого переключения между персонажами камера сбивается.







добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык
